# SSRS - Sum each cell value into next column

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS Question - Is there a way to sum each cell value into
the next colum.  Here's what I'm trying to achieve.  Colm B displays
the sum of colum A upto that row

Col A      Col B

1             
1

2             
3

3             
6

4             
10

5             
15

6             
21

7             
28

8             
36

9             
45

Answer (score 1):

You want running totals. Everything you need is [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/briankmcdonald/bidn-blog/656/running-totals-using-reporting-services).

Basically it will take each value from a data set and sum it up with the total from all previous values.

Some basic syntax: `=RunningValue(Fields!A.Value,Sum,"yourDataSet")`